# cordova /platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I HAVE THIS ERROR WITH cordova-onesignal-plugin installed

On build app in ionic

```
sudo ionic build android

sudo cordova build android
```

Error: /platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+ as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm are available.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
  >        repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
  >        jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
  >        jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
  >        file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
  >        file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+ as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics are available.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/maven-metadata.xml
  >        repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/
  >        jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/maven-metadata.xml
  >        jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/
  >        file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/maven-metadata.xml
  >        file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+ as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-location are available.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml
  >        repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
  >        jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml
  >        jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
  >        file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml
  >        file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: You need to download and install google services with Android SDK.

Comment: Not works! I've already tried

Answer (score 5):

Try installing "Google Repository" under *Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools* in your Android Studio. Worked for me.

From the [Android Studio docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html), you will see:

> Google Repository Recommended. Includes local Maven repository for
>   Google libraries, which provide a variety of features and services for
>   your apps, such as Google sign-in, Google Maps, Games achievements and
>   leaderboards, and much more.

My bet is that this includes `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+`.

Comment: "Google Repository" already installed, but still showing the same error in android studio.! please tell is any other option to solve this.!!

Comment: I think I solved it by installing "Google Play Services". "Google Repository" was not an option.